# Why use 'data' event over 'readable' event?

Tags: node.js

The stream documentation says this:

> Note: In general, the readable.pipe() and 'data' event mechanisms are
>   preferred over the use of the 'readable' event.

Why is 'data' event preferred over 'readable' event? 'readable' event seems to be a better approach since it provides flow control through back-pressure and also gives more control to the application on when to handle the available data.

Answer (score 0):

These is basic difference between the working principle of `readable` and `data` event are.

- `readable` event buffers the data and once avaiable it can be read.
- `data` event callback is called when chunk of data is available and
  forces you to handle that.
- `readable` event is good in case you are handling large data
- for smaller chunk `data` event is efficient to use

Comment: Thanks for answer Sumeet. I agree to your point about 'data' event forcing the application to handle the chunk of data. This is precisely why I felt that 'readable' was better in terms of giving control to the application in deciding when the data will be handled. The decision to use the appropriate event depends on the context (like using 'data' event for handling smaller chunk of data). But I am still surprised by the explicit documentation in node that says 'data' is preferred over 'readable'. That seems like a blank cheque and I am trying to understanding the reason behind the suggestion.